# Read error on swap device

Tags: swap, suspend

After a long suspended session my system gives me this message `Read-error on swap-device (8:0:441040)` (this is the last one received). It reboots in some way, because there are not more programs opened by me before the suspension, it's pratically a new user session. I searched bad sectors in swap partition with `badblocks` command but everything seems fine, recently i've incremented my swap but seems that the two things are not related because i got the error messagge even before the size incrementation process. I've already: changed the UUID in the fstab file after the incrementation (just to be sure), reformatted the swap partition, looked for bad sectors, i don't know what to do now. Another thing, in this moment my system mounts arch, but this is a problem that i didn't have before with other distros.

Comment: Is the swap partition large enough to hold all available RAM?

Comment: Yes. I did the incrementation because of the previous size, porting the amount of space from 1GB to 8GB (my ram is 4GB)

Comment: I noticed that the passed time between the activation of suspend session and reactivation of the system affects in some way this issue. After 2-3 hours of suspended session i can resume correctly the user session, but after 10 hours circa i get the error message. I think that even the number of programs opened can be a variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a bug which matches everything you describe (including the separate comments when I wrote this answer).   The bug was introduced in upstream kernel v4.14, which was fixed in v4.17 and v4.16.8.

https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/commit/?h=linux-4.16.y&id=7859056bc73dea2c3714b00c83b253d4c22bf7b6

If you still do not have a new enough kernel, and you don't want to install an older kernel (switch to the `linux-lts` package mentioned in the Arch thread below?), there is a workaround.  You can add the option "scsi_mod.scan=sync" to the end of your kernel command line, e.g. in GRUB.

The original Arch forum thread on it is here:

https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=235027

"Read-error on swap-device" during resume is a *possible* signature for this error (but this error message could be caused by other things, and most of the time this crash was quite silent, at least for me).  For examples where this message happened, see:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1035208/ubuntu-18-04-error-on-waking-up-from-sleep-read-error-on-swap-device/

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1553979#c29

Comment: I really appreciate your help, a lot of usefull informations, but right now i don't have the chance to recreate the environment for test your solution (that solve what was my problem). Again, thanks for your time

Comment: I also seem to have run into the same type of error on kernel version 4.18.0. Not sure the cause is the same as much as the symptoms.

Comment: If `scsi_mod.scan=sync` doesn't fix it, then I don't think it's the same cause :-). You mean it's causing Xorg or Xwayland to crash with SIGBUS when resuming from suspend? But, most people would have no reason to run a kernel as old as 4.18.0. (I suspect it's *not* actually a vanilla kernel, i.e. straight from Linus' tree without any patches? Is it from a distro package? If so, better say the exact version of the  package the kernel came from, to identify which patches it's built with).